# Como realizar una función con un argumento optativo y que me devuelva los objetos que cumplen dicho valor

Tags: python, poo, funciones

Tengo que realizar la función catalogar() para que reciba un argumento optativo ruedas, haciendo que muestre únicamente los que su número de ruedas concuerde con el valor del argumento. También debe mostrar un mensaje "Se han encontrado {} vehículos con {} ruedas:" únicamente si se envía el argumento ruedas. Ponla a prueba con 0, 2 y 4 ruedas como valor.

Adjunto codigo: https://linkode.org/#mbgecKkEC2kVN5kwaaSSZ4

No quiero que me pongáis la respuesta, alguna pista de como cambiar la función catalogar para introducir ese parametro, no se, cualquier ayuda se agradece

Comment: Hola! Se que ya tienes una respuesta, pero podrías tomarte un momento de editar tu pregunta y poner el código en la publicación (sin usar links al código) por favor? Si el link se cae, la pregunta se volverá inutil para futuros lectores.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes un argumento opcional, lo usual es asignarle un valor por default que no interfiera con los valores válidos. Lo más conveniente es asignarle `None`, que será una clara señal de que no se pasó ningún valor.

```
def catalogar1(lista_vehiculos, n_ruedas = None):
    contador = 0
    for vehiculo in lista_vehiculos:
        if n_ruedas == vehiculo.ruedas:
            print(vehiculo)
            contador += 1
    if n_ruedas:
       print(f"Se han encontrado {contador} vehículos con {n_ruedas} ruedas:")
```